# Can a column in a cassandra table be altered to make it static?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table in the cassandra database with a few static columns and I wish to add another column to it that is static. Is there a way to alter the table so that the new column is static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your keyspace is `key` and the table schema is :

```
 CREATE TABLE p (   
     k text,   
     s text STATIC,   
     i int,   
     PRIMARY KEY (k, i) );
```

Then you can execute

```
 ALTER TABLE p ADD f text STATIC;
```

Answer (score 2):

As Will's answer points out, this may depend on which version you are using.  The [ALTER documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html) for CQL 3.1 (Cassandra 2.0 and 2.1) states:

> These additions to a table are not allowed:
>
> - Adding a column having the same name as an existing column
> - **A static column**

Although evidently it works with 2.1.9.

Also important to note, you cannot ALTER an existing column to become static.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> ALTER TABLE bills2 ALTER amount TYPE bigint static;
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:44 missing EOF at 'static' (...bills2 ALTER amount TYPE bigint [static];)">
```